# Create CardDAV or LDAP server on shared host via PHP?

Tags: linux, php, openldap

Is it possible to run a CardDAV or LDAP server on my shared hosting account? It is a Linux account using CPanel. I do not want to store my address book on my local computer any more, but centralized location so I can read/update them from my mobile devices.

Are there any open source PHP CardDAV or LDAP server projects that can be run on a shared host?

Comment: This question is off topic because it is about an administration panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These accounts are not normally intended for running long range custom services. You need to look at a VPS hosting account, they could run them without issue.